# list file path with in folder and subfolder

Tags: java, file, search, file-io

I am looking for a way to list the file paths inside a folder which may contain several sub folder with multiple files.

forexample

```
Folder A:
   file 1, file 2 and Folder B,
       Fodler B:
            file 3, file 4,....
```

Any suggestions or link to tutorials will really help me as I am new to programming.

Comment: Is the problem  getting the list of files and folders? Or is it formatting the printed output?

Comment: Have you actually tried coding this? Are you getting any errors? Where's the effort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice i would use the Apache Commons method, but if you had to write your own, for a school project or something, then you need to look into recursion.

If you only want to go 1 folder deep, you just loop through your folders folders, looking for files, if it can go 10-20 levels deep, this makes your code pretty horrible, so you use recursion.

```
public void listFiles(Folder) {
  Print out all files in the current folder
  Get all Folders in the current folder
  for each folder
    listfiles(folder)
}
```

This method then calls itself, until you have all the files from all the child folders printed out.

Comment: It worked for me. can you also tell me how can I print the file size and date modified

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Apache Commons FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html). The method:

```
public static Collection<File> listFiles(File directory,
                                     IOFileFilter fileFilter,
                                     IOFileFilter dirFilter)
```

should allow you to get the desired result.